# Barbecue sauce with 12% vinegar

Tags: cooking-time, barbecue-sauce

I have an exact recipe for industrial batches of barbecue sauce, with ingredients measured in kilograms. I tried to make a small batch at home, using the same proportions of ingredients.

The vinegar burnt all the way down and was way too strong.

Maybe is it that I brought the BBQ sauce (paste and pureed tomatoes) up to 91 degrees and then cut the heat; should it all have cooked in about 20 minutes?

What went wrong?

Comment: Your question is kind of unclear... can you post your recipe in a little more detail, so we understand what it is that went wrong with your bbq sauce?

Comment: If you're using 12% vinegar in a recipe that calls for vinegar, normal vinegar is around 5%, 7% at most. So that'd not work (unless you dilute your 12% vinegar down)

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question correctly, there are a few possibilities:

1. The vinegar you have used is too strong - some vinegars are milder than others
2. You have boiled off so much water that the whole sauce is much stronger than it should be
3. Something about your calculations or measurements was off

Number 2 is the most likely. Larger volumes will take longer to bring to the boil (even with industrial heating equipment) and will take longer to boil off water. Try tasting the sauce as it cooks. When it tastes ready, it is ready.